# Is there a stoll()/stroll() (string to long long) alternative in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

Is there an alternative, either built into windows or apache license compatible, to [stoll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee404750.aspx) for Visual Studio 2008. Even installing the windows 7 platform SDK does not add stoll() to the string header.

On unix the same function is be called [strtoll()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`_strtoi64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h80404d3%28VS.80%29.aspx).  It's declared in `stdlib.h`.

```
long long num = _strtoi64(str, NULL, 10);
```

Similarly to [`strtoll`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strtol.html), you can pass a `char ** endptr` as a second parameter.  If so, `*endptr` will be set to the first invalid character (which may be the normal null-terminator).

Comment: Thats the great thing about standards, so many to chose from.

Comment: @Justin, yeah, but even Microsoft doesn't pretend this one's standard. :)

Comment: The cpp reference said that `strtoll` was added in C++99, so of course VS 2008 would support it - nope.  `_strtoi64` seems to be what we need.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2013 added strtoll(), so if you can depend on that you can use strtoll() directly.